# IE10 does not scale background SVG correctly when zoomed (on Surface/Windows 8 phone)

Tags: svg, zooming, background-image, internet-explorer-10

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this? Internet Explorer 10 and Window phone 8 are not able to correctly scale background SVG images when a user zooms. Looks like IE rasterizes the SVG on load.

[Here is an example:](http://cdpn.io/ABkiF) The first image is the SVG as a background image. Zoom in on a MS Surface or Windows 8 phone and you'll see it blurs horribly.

The second image is the same SVG as an img tag. Zoom this on a Surface or Windows 8 mobile phone and it scales as you would expect (nice and clean).

Is there any property that can be added to make IE10 behave? Or is it merely a case of waiting for the folks at Redmond to fix it?

Comment: If I recall correctly IE10 uses hardware acceleration for SVG. If you re-insert the background src after a zoom event then it might 'sharpen', but not during the zoom (only after).

Comment: Hi Duopixel, you mean re-inserting with JS? If that's the only way to sharpen the background SVG on/after zoom I'd give it a miss and wait for MS to fix things.

Comment: It's mostly intuition, but I don't have a Windows Touch device to test. I'd like someone to actually give it a try. I'll add a bounty for this question when it's possible (I must wait 48h to add it).

Comment: Your demo is using a .png for both images. At least that is what I see in the debugger, and both images blur on zoom in all desktop browsers that I've tried.

Comment: Here is a version that is actually using SVG. The same scaling issue is also present in Firefox. http://codepen.io/dstorey/full/afwCk

Comment: @dstorey, apologies, not sure why it was hooked up to a PNG - amended the pen now. As mentioned from the outset, I feared it was merely IE rasterising the image so thanks for confirming. Having a cursory glance at Davids info I'll consider the 'upsizing' technique but wanted to know there wasn't anything else 'cleaner' that could be done.

Comment: I think that is probably as clean as you're going to get. It works quite well, mainly just extra memory required for a larger rasterised image before zooming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that IE, and other browsers such as Firefox rasterise the SVG before displaying it, so it will become blocky when zoomed.

The easiest way to fix this is to make the SVG file larger than is needed. For example double the size, or more if the user is likely to zoom in further. You can then resize the SVG image with CSS to display it at the correct size. This way the image will be naturally larger, so wont become blocky, unless you zoom in even further. At default zoom level the image is scaled down rather than up, which browsers usually handle better.

Edit: You can find further info on this issue under the “SVG and CSS Backgrounds” heading at http://dbushell.com/2012/03/11/svg-all-fun-and-games/

Comment: When are you actually going to fix this, now that you, @David Storey, works on the IE team?